# python & livejson Object of type '_NestedList' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

Ok so I'm trying to make a dictionary rename function but I keep getting the error `Object of type '_NestedList' is not JSON serializable` no matter what I do, I've tried a few things which when I try them on repl they work no issues... except when I try them on my end.

The json for it looks like `custom["commands"]["command"]["beep"]`
so what I'm trying to do is change it to `custom["commands"]["command"]["boom"]`

```
{
    "command": {},
    "commands": {
        "command": {
            "beep": {
                "created": "2018-11-04 16:32:50.013260",
                "created2": 1541349170.0132835,
                "createdby": "me",
                "disablefor": [],
                "enabledfor": [],
                "message": "asd",
                "public": "self",
                "type": "text",
                "unsendtimer": 0,
                "unsendtrigger": false
            },
            "bep": {
                "created": "2018-11-04 16:34:38.723840",
                "created2": 1541349278.7238638,
                "createdby": "me",
                "disablefor": [],
                "enabledfor": [],
                "message": "asd",
                "public": "self",
                "type": "text",
                "unsendtimer": 0,
                "unsendtrigger": false
            },
            "boop": {
                "STKID": "423",
                "STKPKGID": "1",
                "STKVER": "100",
                "created": "2018-10-27 00:53:38.067740",
                "created2": 1540601618.0677645,
                "createdby": "me",
                "disablefor": [
                    "u69a0086845f2d38c5ecfd91a7601f3c1",
                    "ua2ed27b7932f647b492daa68ef33c0cc"
                ],
                "enabledfor": [],
                "message": "8775249726676",
                "public": "on",
                "type": "sticker",
                "unsendtimer": 0,
                "unsendtrigger": true
            }
        },
        "commandgrab": false,
        "commandgroup": ""
    }
}
```

that's what the json file looks like, Anyone has any suggestions I'd love them thanks

Comment: true and false are wrong value for python so it will create issues.... try with True and False, it worked for me

Comment: They actually get automatically converted from upper case to lowercase when you input into json and when you call the json it turns it into capital for python

Comment: I try on my python IDLE and custom["commands"]["command"]["beep"] worked for me....

Comment: Include your code so we can reproduce the error. There's not enough information in the question right now.

Comment: custom["commands"]["command"][rename] = {**custom["commands"]["command"][old]} is one thing I tried, the rename and old is the string of the names of both dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [livejson](https://pypi.org/project/livejson/) package, rather than python's built-in json package.

livejson json structures are a tree of livejson objects; evidently livejson does not directly support moving these objects between keys:

```
>>> import livejson
>>> test['foo'] = {'bar': {'baz': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> test
{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': [1, 2, 3]}}}

>>> type(test['foo']['bar']['baz'])
<class 'livejson._NestedList'>


>>> test['foo']['bar']['quux'] = test['foo']['bar']['baz']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
TypeError: Object of type _NestedList is not JSON serializable
```

livejson objects have a `data` property that returns the standard python lists and dicts that livejson is wrapping, so you need to use this property to reassign the key's value:

```
>>> test['foo']['bar']['quux'] = test['foo']['bar']['baz'].data

# Now remove the old value
>>> del test['foo']['bar']['baz']
>>> test

{'foo': {'bar': {'quux': [1, 2, 3]}}}
```